# Autowiring Concrete Class into Abstract Decorator

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, decorator, autowired

Greetings ladies and gents,

I'm implementing a system where we are trying to keep things highly flexible. We have an abstract superclass called `EmailTaskService` which has two classes inheriting from it. One is `EmailTaskServiceImpl` (the concrete implementation class), and the other is another abstract class called `ScheduledEmailTaskService` which has a subclass called `ScheduledEmailTaskServiceImpl`.

To keep things flexible, we are using both a vertical and horizontal decorator pattern on the `ScheduledEmailTaskService`. This means that it inherits from `EmailTaskService` as well as composing in the concrete service itself. But my problem comes from trying to autowire the concrete `EmailTaskServiceImpl`,  all I get is a `No qualifying bean of type EmailTaskServiceImpl` exception thrown. Obviously I can't just autowire `EmailTaskService` because its an abstract class, not an interface.

I'll post the code below to give you an idea of what is going on.
**EmailTaskService**

```
public abstract class EmailTaskService<E, I> implements GenericService<E, I>{

    @Autowired
    protected EmailTaskDAO emailTaskDao;

    public abstract void deleteEmailTask(I emailTaskId);
```

}

**EmailTaskServiceImpl**

```
@Service("emailTaskService")
public class EmailTaskServiceImpl extends EmailTaskService<EmailTask, Long>{

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public long getTotalObjects() {
        return super.emailTaskDao.count();
    }
    etc etc other methods here doing concretey things.
```

**ScheduledEmailTaskService**

```
public abstract class ScheduledEmailTaskService<E, I> extends EmailTaskService<E, I> {

    @Autowired
    protected ScheduledEmailTaskDAO scheduledEmailTaskDao;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("emailTaskService")
    protected EmailTaskService<EmailTask, Long> emailTaskService;

    @Override
    public abstract void deleteEmailTask(I emailTaskId) throws InvalidInvocationException;

    public abstract void deleteScheduledEmailTask(I scheduledEmailTaskId);
}
```

**ScheduledEmailTaskService**

```
@Service
public class ScheduledEmailTaskServiceImpl extends ScheduledEmailTaskService<ScheduledEmailTask, Long> {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public long getTotalObjects() {
        return super.scheduledEmailTaskDao.count();
    }

    more concretey methods go here
```

In case you are wondering `GenericService<E, I>` is an interface that specifies CRUD methods for all my services to implement which is why `EmailTaskService` implements it.

So my question is how do I get some sort of reference to `EmailTaskService` or `EmailTaskServiceImpl` successfully available in `ScheduledEmailTaskService` either through Autowiring or through another sensible method. If this just isn't possible, Why?

EDIT 1 (Context Configuration):
Ask and ye shall receive:

```
<beans Spring namespace config etc etc etc>
<context:component-scan base-package="au.com.mail" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<task:annotation-driven/>

<!-- Project Properties -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:project.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean> 
</beans>
```

EDIT 2: Actual Proper Stacktrace:

```
[junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scheduledEmailTaskServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected au.com.mail.service.emailtask.EmailTaskService au.com.mail.service.emailtask.ScheduledEmailTaskService.emailTaskService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [au.com.mail.service.emailtask.EmailTaskService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=emailTaskService)}
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1146)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
[junit]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
[junit]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
[junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
[junit]     ... 50 more
[junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected au.com.mail.service.emailtask.EmailTaskService au.com.mail.service.emailtask.ScheduledEmailTaskService.emailTaskService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [au.com.mail.service.emailtask.EmailTaskService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=emailTaskService)}
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
[junit]     ... 66 more
[junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [au.com.mail.service.emailtask.EmailTaskService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=emailTaskService)}
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:988)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
[junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
[junit]     ... 68 more
```

And before you ask, yes my JUnit is configured to use the Spring Application Context correctly.

Comment: The way you have it fine. Make sure your `EmailTaskServiceImpl` class is being component scanned.

Comment: Actually can we see your context configuration?

Comment: Yep both `*ServiceImpl` classes are available in the ApplicationContext, but I'm still getting a No Bean Definition Exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you have `@Transactional` everywhere, I'm going to assume you have some proxying going on with JDK proxies.

As it turns out, JKD proxies can only get your target bean's interfaces, not their class hierarchy. So the proxy created for your `EmailTaskServiceImpl` is not of type `EmailTaskServiceImpl` and can therefore not fill in for an injection target of that type. Instead, it is of type `EmailTaskService`, but your field is

```
@Autowired
protected EmailTaskServiceImpl emailTaskService;
```

so that won't do.

There are two solutions:

The first is to change your configuration to use CGLIB proxies. You'll need to change your transactional configuration to

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

and add the CGLIB libraries to your classpath.

The second is to change your field to

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("someName")
protected EmailTaskService emailTaskService;
```

and your class declaration to

```
@Service("someName")
public class EmailTaskServiceImpl extends EmailTaskService<EmailTask, Long>{
```

Spring will use the name instead of the type when determining which bean to inject. This is necessary because you have many `EmailTaskService` candidate beans.

Comment: Ok tried that, no change. My problem isn't that I'm getting multiple beans available for autowiring. I'm not getting ANY beans (of type `EmailTaskService`) available for autowiring.

Comment: @JamesMassey Your package doesn't seem to fit what you have in the `component-scan`. `au.com.afgonline.mail` vs `au.com.mail`.

Comment: gah, thats my company name i was trying to keep out of it. I assure you its all configured correctly. I just forgot to remove the name from the stacktrace.
Oh also in response to your post as well, I'd dearly like to avoid CGLIB proxies if I can avoid them. I'd rather be using a static factory than a CGLIB proxy.

Comment: @JamesMassey Last thing I can think of is that those classes aren't added to your test classpath.

Comment: Sorry, In my test config, I have context configuration that is pulling in my application context, the classes are definitely there. I just don't know why there is no reference too them. Would a static factory be the way to go? Thanks for trying anyway

Comment: @JamesMassey Humor me for a second. Explicitly add a `<bean>` element for `EmailTaskDAO` or any other simple bean, but remove the rest of your configuration. What errors do you get?

Comment: As you most likely expected `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [au.com.mail.dao.emailtask.EmailTaskDAO] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:` when I added a `<bean>` element for `EmailTaskDAOImpl`

Comment: @JamesMassey I'm stumped. If it's not a classpath issue, I can only imagine it being the package name in `component-scan`. If that's not it, I'm no use to you...

Comment: Thank you very much for trying! I'll keep looking for a solution.

Comment: You didn't try the cglib proxies? I assume that's the problem. N.B. since Spring 3.1 (I think, certainly with 4.0) you don't need to add the cglib dependencies because Spring packages then internally.